# select query to validate existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have a table like below:

```
Id  Attribute  Column A  Column B Column C   H   S  
1     H/S        1           1      1        01  02
2     H/S        2           3      1        01  02
3     H/S        1           4      1        01  02
4     H/S        1           1      3        03  04
5     H/S        1           1      3        03  04
6     H/S        1           6      7        05  06
```

I want to run a select query on above data so that it will validate the entries in such a way that for the same attribute(H/S) values there should not be different values in Column A,Column B and Column C.

If there are such entries then select query should return those entries as below :(Desired output on above data) :

```
   Id  Attribute  Column A  Column B Column C    H   S  
    1     H/S        1           1      1        01  02
    2     H/S        2           3      1        01  02
    3     H/S        1           4      1        01  02
    6     H/S        1           6      7        05  06
```

Comment: "for the same attribute(H/S) values there should not be different values in Column A,Column B and Column C" All values in `Column B` are different for the desired result. Did you mean "no repeated values," because rows 4 and 5 are eliminated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable dup
    WHERE t.Id <> dup.Id
      AND t.ColumnA = dup.ColumnA
      AND t.ColumnB = dup.ColumnB
      AND t.ColumnC = dup.ColumnC
      AND t.H = dup.H
      AND t.S = dup.S
)
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23c93d/1)